# Calculate multiple files length for ajax upload progress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, upload

I have the following in phpbb posting_attach_body.html which monitors upload progress of files. It works great with one file but if I am trying to upload more than one then it will only calculate the size of the first file and uses that length to show the upload progress bar. How can i change it to calculate and use the total of multiple file uploads instead?

The javascript function *add_more_upload()* is what loads extra form fields to add files to and that works fine allowing multiple uploads.

```
<div class="panel bg3" id="attach-panel">
    <div class="inner"><span class="corners-top"><span></span></span>

    <p>{L_ADD_ATTACHMENT_EXPLAIN}</p>

    <fieldset class="fields2">
    <dl>
        <dt><label for="fileupload">{L_FILENAME}:</label></dt>
        <dd>
            <!-- IF TESTY -->
            <input type="url" name="remfile" id="remfile" class="inputbox autowidth" /> Remote File URL<br />
            <input type="text" name="altname" id="altname" class="inputbox autowidth" /> Alternative Name<br />
            <!-- ENDIF -->
            <input type="file" name="fileupload" id="fileupload" maxlength="{FILESIZE}" value="" class="inputbox autowidth" />
            <input type="button" class="button2" name="files_" value="+" style="width: 40px" onclick="add_more_upload()" title="" />
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt><label for="filecomment">{L_FILE_COMMENT}:</label></dt>
        <dd><textarea name="filecomment" id="filecomment" rows="1" cols="40" class="inputbox autowidth">{FILE_COMMENT}</textarea></dd>
    </dl>
    <input type="hidden" name="proxid" id="proxid" value="1" />
    <div id="multiple"></div>
    <dl>
        <dd>
            <input type="submit" name="add_file" value="{L_ADD_FILE}" class="button2" onclick="uploadFile(); " />
        </dd>
    </dl>
    </fieldset>

<progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress> <h3 id="status"></h3> <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
<script>
function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}

function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("fileupload").files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("fileupload", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    //ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", uploadFile, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("complete", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST","forum/file_upload_parser.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}

function progressHandler(event){
    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100; _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent); _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}

function errorHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}

function abortHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
function completeHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText; _("progressBar").value = 100;
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Complete. Processing File... please wait.";
}
</script>
    <span class="corners-bottom"><span></span></span></div>
</div>
```

the add_more_files function :

```
 function add_more_upload() {
            var id = document.getElementById('proxid').value ;
            var div = document.getElementById('multiple');
            var childdiv = document.createElement("div");
            childdiv.setAttribute('id','multiple'+ id); 
            var html = "<dl><dt><label for='fileupload'>{L_FILENAME}:</label></dt><dd><input type='file' name='fileupload" + id + "' id='fileupload" + id + "' maxlength='{FILESIZE}' value='' class='inputbox autowidth' /><input type='button' class='button2' name='files_" + id + "' value='-' style='width: 40px' onclick='remove_more_upload(" + id + ")' title='' /></dd></dl><dl><dt><label for='filecomment'>{L_FILE_COMMENT}:</label></dt><dd><textarea name='filecomment" + id + "' id='filecomment" + id + "' rows='1' cols='40' class='inputbox autowidth'>{FILE_COMMENT}</textarea></dd></dl>";               
            childdiv.innerHTML = html;
            div.appendChild(childdiv) ;
            document.getElementById('proxid').value++; 
            }
```

Comment: You haven't included the add_more_upload() function, so my answer works without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are only uploading one file at a time : _("fileupload").files[**0**];

This code will allow you to upload several files at once:

```
<script>

    var totalSize = 0;
    var formdata = new FormData();

    function processFiles(ctrl) {
            // if the control has files
            if(ctrl.files)
            {
            for(var i=0; i < ctrl.files.length; i++) {
             var file = ctrl.files[i];
             totalSize += file.size;
             formdata.append("fileupload" + i, file);
            }
        }
    }

    // pass the name of the div holding the file upload controls
    function uploadFiles(ctrId) {

            totalSize = 0;
            formdata = new FormData();

            // builds a set of INPUT controls and tries to process any files
            var uploadControls = document.getElementById(ctrId).getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

            for(var i = 0; i< uploadControls.length; i++)
            {
               processFiles(uploadControls[i]);
            }

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

        ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
        ajax.open("POST","forum/file_upload_parser.php");
        ajax.send(formdata);        
    }

    function progressHandler(event) {
        document.getElementById("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+totalSize;
        var percent = (event.loaded / totalSize) * 100; _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent); _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
    }

</script>   


<div id="fileuploads">
    <input type="file" name="fileupload" id="fileupload0" multiple maxlength="{FILESIZE}" value="" class="inputbox autowidth" />
    <input type="file" name="fileupload" id="fileupload1" multiple maxlength="{FILESIZE}" value="" class="inputbox autowidth" />
    <input type="file" name="fileupload" id="fileupload3" multiple maxlength="{FILESIZE}" value="" class="inputbox autowidth" />
</div>
<input type="submit" name="add_file" value="{L_ADD_FILE}" class="button2" onclick="uploadFiles('fileuploads'); " />
<div id="loaded_n_total">waiting...</div>
```

Comment: You will need to pull this into your existing code, it's only intended as a proof of concept to show you a way to track cumulative progress for a set of uploaded files.

Comment: What does crtlId refer to?

Comment: If you look at the onClick event for the button - it's the of your file upload control.

Comment: Ok when uploading two files it is only picking up one and reporting the size, not the second one. Both files still upload though. I want this to work with a separate upload input area for each file, not using multiple in the input tag. When using multiple in the input tag and selecting two files then yes it reports the sum of both files but unfortunately the add_more_files function does not handle this correctly.

Comment: What add_more_files function? you didn't include one in your original question #NotPsychic

Comment: i mentioned that i use it, and you can also see how it is implemented in the code above. You press the + button and it adds another input field

Comment: I added the function to my question just now

Comment: I see you updated your answer and with a bit of extra fiddling with the form divs it is now reporting the total size of all files in the input fields. The problem now is the upload progress isn't showing anything. All it says is 'waiting...' when I press submit. Anyway we are getting there. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: ok well it's strange, I have to press submit twice for the upload progress to show the details. Would something be stopping the first click? The other thing is if I click submit three times, i'm not sure why anyone would but anyway the upload progress details change all over the place, like two lot's of calculations are running and being shown at the same time. Is there a way to prevent that from happening? I'm guessing it would be to remove the onclick event after the upload progress starts? Other than that your code works correctly showing a total of all files. Well done.

Comment: you're not running my code verbatim, you're pushing it through another script - at the bottom of your answer post what you are getting from your server and I'll have a last look at it for you

Comment: So something is killing the first click on submit and also every time submit is pressed when the file/s are uploading the progress function gets fired again, I need to prevent that as well so it is only fired on the first submit.

Comment: I've narrowed the first click thing down to the progressHandler(event) function not being fired, uploadFiles(ctrId) function does get fired. Still not sure on what is going on.

Comment: ajax.addEventListener("error", xxxxxxxx, false); is what gets fired on the first submit. Why would that be?

Comment: hey I just worked it out, I needed to add "return false;" after the input onclick="uploadFiles('multiple'); part and now it works and submits the first time and shows upload progress straight away. Cheers.